# Unit Test a change in the parameter value passed to a function of Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test if the variable that is passed in the function parameter is changed or not. The variable passed itself should change.

I am using Karma and Jasmine for my unit tests.

My Controller code looks something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.functions = {};
  $scope.functions.deleteSomething = function(someObject, condition){
      someObject.someArray = someObject.someArray.filter(function(existingCondition){
          return existingCondition !== condition;
      });
  };
})
```

My Unit Test:

```js
describe('myControllerSpec', function(){
  var scope, controller;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller){
    scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    controller = $controller('MyController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));
  
  it("should check if the passed variable is changed or not", function(){
    object = {
        someArray: [
          {
            temp: 'dummy1'
          },
          {
            temp: 'dummy2'
          }
        ]
      };
    
    condition = {
      temp: 'dummy1'
    }
    scope.functions.deleteSomething(object, condition);
    expect(object.someArray).toEqual([
        {
          temp: 'dummy2'
        }
      ]);
  });
})
```

I am not able to figure out why the variable does not change. Is it because it is not attached to scope?

But I do not want to attach it to scope and test it in this way. I cannot change the Controller as it is maintained by someone else.

Any suggestions on how can I test this code?

Answer (score 0):

The `===` in Javascript executes a reference equality check. Try using `angular.equals()`:

```
  someObject.someArray = someObject.someArray.filter(function(existingCondition){
      return !angular.equals(existingCondition, condition);
  });
```

Comment: Yes but as I said, I cannot change the Controller as it is maintained by someone else.

Comment: A few possibilites exist: (1) the someone else has a bug, the above should be suggested as correction. (2) If the `!==` is by design this will work: `condition = objects.someArray[0]`. THIS ASSUMES THAT THE `condition` IN THE CODE WILL ALWAYS REFERENCE A VALUE FROM THE ARRAY!!! (3) If the `!==` is by design and business requirements, and the `condition` does not necessarily reference a value from the array, then the controller is not supposed to deal with objects and you are violating the contract of the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Gave me a new perspective to look at the problem.